# Gulp is messing up CSS content

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I recently started having an issue with my gulpfile messing up CSS content properties. It only does this if the content value is a symbol, like a dot or arrow. Ex. here's a section of the SCSS file with the proper content.

```
    ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;

  li {
    text-indent: -13px;
    padding-left: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;

    &:before {
      content: '•';
      margin-right: 5px;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      line-height: 1em;
      vertical-align: -2px;
    }
    li {
      margin-top: 5px;
      text-indent: -18px;
      padding-left: 18px;          

      &:before {
        content: '›';
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this is what I am seeing in my final CSS file after being compiled.

```
body main ul li:before{content:"ΓÇó";margin-right:5px;font-size:1.3em;line-height:1em;vertical-align:-2px}body main ul li li{margin-top:5px;text-indent:-18px;padding-left:18px}body main ul li li:before{content:"ΓÇ║";margin-right:10px}
```

Here's my gulpfile I'm using.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minifycss = require('gulp-cssnano');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return sass('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .on('error', sass.logError)
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(''))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./scss'))
            .pipe(notify({ message: 'Wait for it....wait for it!!!' }));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss',['css']);
});
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: It's being minified, which is a good thing - try removing the line `.pipe(minifycss())`. Update: sorry, you meant the symbols - can you try adding `@charset "utf-8";` at the top of the CSS file?

Comment: I tried that, but no success :(

Comment: Try disabling your CSS tasks one by one to see who's the culprit.

Comment: I don't believe the problem is with the gulp commands (since yours are basically identical to the ones I use). See my edited comment above.

Comment: Hey Toby! That was it, thanks so much! My coworkers were telling me I shouldn't use gulp anymore, and I was hoping to prove them wrong! :) Add an answer and I'll mark it